# Почему не выполняется часть функции после asyncio.sleep()?

Tags: python, asyncio

Перелопатил уже кучу "литературы" и никак не могу понять:
Почему если убрать строку `await task` из функции `main()`, то функция `foo()` выполняется только до `asyncio.sleep(1)`, а если оставить `await task`, то функция выполняется целиком:
Разве не должна фнукция `foo()` выполниться так же целиком, но просто **после** выполнения `main()` ?

```
import asyncio as ao


async def foo(number):
    print(f'foo  {number}')
    await ao.sleep(1)
    print('SOMETHING')

async def main():
    print('start')
    task = ao.create_task(foo(999))
    await task
    print('finish')


ao.run(main())
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: main завершается и цикл ожидания, созданный ao.run() то же прекращается. А без рабочего цикла ожидания уже ничего работать не может (некому понять, что sleep закончился и запустить продолжение корутины)

Comment: @Mike Вполне можно было и ответом оформить, наверное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `main` завершается и цикл ожидания, созданный `ao.run()`, то же прекращается. А без рабочего цикла ожидания уже ничего работать не может (некому понять, что `sleep` закончился и запустить продолжение корутины)